# How to search replace with regex and keep case as original in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my problem.  I have a string with mixed case in it.  I want to search regardless of case and then replace the matches with some characters either side of the matches.

For example:

```
var s1 = "abC...ABc..aBC....abc...ABC";
var s2 = s.replace(/some clever regex for abc/g, "#"+original abc match+"#");
```

The result in s2 should end up like:

```
"#abC#...#ABc#..#aBC#....#abc#...#ABC#"
```

Can this be done with regex? If so, how?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This can be done using a callback function for regex replace.

```js
var s1 = "abC...ABc..aBC....abc...ABC";

var s2 = s1.replace(/abc/ig, function(match) {
  return "#" + match + "#";
});

console.log(s2);
```

Comment: Sounds promising, can you give me an example

Comment: @Graham mine isn't briliant? ;-) It's shorter and probably faster ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Your answer is equally brilliant, but IMHO callback functions provide more flexibility to operate over the matches as compared to expressions with backreferences.

Comment: @DhruvPathak I agree that callbacks are very flexible and good to learn ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Callbacks may provide more flexibility and are good to know but they are slower when compared to using backreferences. See this [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/search-replace-with-regex-keep-case)

Comment: @garyh that's why I wrote my own answer in the first place.

Comment: @JanDvorak I thought yours would be faster - it's good to have proof!

Comment: This one works for me, the answer with a back-reference not.

Answer (score 27):

This can be done using a back-reference:

```
var s2 = s.replace(/your complex regex/g, "#$&#");
```

The back-reference `$&` brings in the entire match. If you want to match "abc" in any case:

```
var s2 = s.replace(/abc/ig, "#$&#");
```

If you only want to bring in part of a larger pattern, you can refer to it by its group number:

```
var s2 = s.replace(/some (part) of a string/ig, "#$1#");
```

Groups are numbered by their opening parenthesis, from left to right, from `$1` to `$9`.

Comment: what would be the regex expression?

Comment: @Graham the same as yours. I assumed "abc" was just a placeholder for something else that you already knew how to match.

Comment: Can you show this example on regex101? Does it also work with the python or php settings?

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this

```
yourString.replace(/([a-z]+)/ig, "#$1#")
```

Comment: This replaces all occurances with #abC# which is not what I want

Comment: @Graham you can remove `g` if you dont want to match all occurances