# Keep case with regex find and replace

Tags: regex

My question is pretty straightforward, using only a regular expression find and replace, is it possible to keep the case of the original words.

So if I have the string: "Pretty pretty is so pretty"
How can I turn it into: "Lovely lovely is so lovely"

All I have so far is find `/(P|p)retty/g` and replace with `$1ovely` but I dont know how to replace caplital P with L and lowercase p with l.

I am not interested in accomplishing this in any particular language, I want to know if it is possible to do with pure regex.

Comment: which lang are you running?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search replace with regex and keep case as original in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721758/how-to-search-replace-with-regex-and-keep-case-as-original-in-javascript)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I suppose it is not possible - I was not looking for the answer to be given in a particular language.

Comment: it won't be possible through regex alone.

Comment: @AvinashRaj feel free to answer and say that it is not possible.

Comment: This is the proper answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13721823/1599699

Comment: @Andrew It does preserve the original case if you want to keep the original string, but in this case, dezman is asking for a mapping of case from a distinct but same-length string (Pretty -> Lovely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be possible to replace captured uppercase or lowercase letter with the  letter according to the type of letter captured through regex alone. But it can be possible through language built-in functions + regex.

In php, i would do like.

```
$str = "Pretty pretty is so pretty";
echo preg_replace_callback('~([pP])retty~', function ($m)
        { 
            if($m[1] == "P") {
            return "Lovely"; }
            else { return "lovely"; }
        }, $str);
```

Output:

```
Lovely lovely is so lovely
```

Comment: **Note:** Built-in functions being callbacks within a regex method. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13721786/3000179

Comment: @hd this actually need an if else condition in the call-back function.